# Reconciling differences between 1 Kings 6:1 of Hebrew Bible and Septuagint

Tags: septuagint, 1-kings

> 1 Kings 6:1 Hebrew bible: In the four hundred and eightieth year after the Israelites came out of Egypt,

The footnote says that the Septuagint says:

> In the four hundred and fortieth year

How do you reconcile the two differences

Comment: This is one of many hundreds of differences between the Hebrew text and the LXX.  There are many more.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure it is possible reconcile all the countless differences in the text between the Hebrew and the Greek LXX.  In this particular case, there is a common supposition that cannot be proven for 1 Kings 6:1.

- 480 years in the Hebrew is counted from the the time the Israelites left Egypt
- 440 yeas of LXX is from the time the Israelites entered the promised land (40 years less than when they left Egypt)

Ellicott appears to agree:

> (1) In the fourth year.—This date, given with marked precision, forms
> a most important epoch in the history of Israel, on which, indeed,
> much of the received chronology is based. In the LXX., 440 is read for
> 480, possibly by an interchange of two similar Hebrew letters, or,
> perhaps, by reckoning from the completion of Exodus at the death of
> Moses instead of its beginning. The Vulgate agrees with the Hebrew
> text.